# Performance issues in Main thread even with AsyncTasks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

My Main thread seems to be pretty bad with performance. Transitioning between activities results in significant delays. I have pushed all of Web/Bitmap/File work into AsyncTasks and yet this is still happening. I have been doing my head in trying to figure out what is causing the slow-downs.

My question is - If the Main thread uses a class (say ImageDownloader) that creates its own little AsyncTasks (say ImageDownloadTask), will Main wait for ImageDownloader to finish it's AsyncTasks (hence delays?)

I would love to post code, but it's a very large project. If there is anything specific I should look for, please let me know and I'll be sure to share.

Comment: Supposing you transition from Activity A to Activity B. Comment all code from onCreate() and onResume() in activity B and test. If everything is OK start uncommmenting bits of code, until you narrow down the performance problems. If commenting all code doesn't help at all, at least we know that the problem is not in Activity B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, I recommend you enable [strict mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) and look for activity on the main thread that way.

Comment: Ah! Did not know about this. It's definitely picking up some read/writes from web & local that I am doing. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Check your onCreates and onResumes for anything that might run for more than an instant. This includes network calls, database calls, loops that may have a lot of iterations, and even reading from locally stored files (SharedPreferences read from an xml). Also try to benchmark how long your onCreate executes the setContentView method -- I believe nested LinearLayouts cause significant performance hits especially in complex UI structures. Acquiring a location with the LocationProvider, when not done properly, will also cause severe performance issues.

You may think you are fine with passing off long-running threads on an asynctask, but you also need to check that prior to starting these tasks, the data you need to start them may take a while to acquire.